# Generate x number of integer partitions

Tags: java, algorithm, math, integer, combinatorics

I have a recursive algorithm, that generates all combinations of a number given as a parameter. It can also do a partition based on 'k' which can also be given as a parameter. It works fine as long as we have smaller numbers given as input. But as 'n'increases, it takes more time and space to compute the results.

Is it possible to given 'x'as input, such that the algorithm only returns x partitions of the number, not all. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

input:

```
n = 10,
k = 4, partition n into 'k'parts
x = 2, number of partitions required
m = 4, maximum number in the partition
```

output:

1. 4,2,2,2
2. 4,3,2,1

Here is the algorithm that I am using:

```
int h=0;        //iterator
public ArrayList<int[]> generate_partitions(int n,int k,int max,boolean norep)
{
    int korig;
    korig = k;
    int[] A = new int[korig+1];
    ArrayList<int[]> partitions = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    GenP(A, n, k, korig, 1,partitions,max);
    if(norep)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<partitions.size(); i++)
        {
            if(check_repetition(partitions.get(i),max))
                partitions.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return partitions;
}
boolean check_repetition(int[] a,int max)
{
    boolean[] hash = new boolean[max+1];
    for(int i=0; i<max+1; i++)
        hash[i]= false;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        if(hash[a[i]]==false)
            hash[a[i]]=true;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
void GenP(int[] A, int n, int k, int korig, int l, ArrayList<int[]> partitions,int max)
{
    //n = number to partition
    //korig = original k
    //l = least number integer required in partition
    if (k==1)   // k = number of partitions
    {
        A[k]=n;
        int [] temp = new int[korig];
        // System.out.println("size = "+korig);
        boolean max_check = false;
        for (int j=1; j<=korig; j++)
        {
            // System.out.print(A[j]+" ");
            temp[j-1]=A[j];
            if(A[j]>max)
                max_check = true;
        }
        if(!max_check) {
            partitions.add(temp);
        }
        //System.out.println();
    }
    else
    {
        if (k==0)
        {
            h=0;
        }
        else
        {
            h=n/k;
            for (int i=l; i<=h; i++)
            {
                A[k]=i;
                GenP(A, n-A[k], k-1, korig, A[k], partitions,max);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a global counter (in the same place as `h`), initialize it to zero.  Every time you add a partition to the answer, increase the counter by 1.  After the recursive call to GenP, check whether the counter already reached `x`, and if it did, return from the recursive function immediately.

Your `norep` version will not be that easy to patch.  Does your algorithm in fact emit duplicates?  (What you posted is not a complete and runnable Java code, so I didn't run it.)  If it does, surely it is possible to patch the algorithm itself to emit only unique partitions.  What are the exact constraints however is not clearly stated (or at least I can't get it at a glance).  Once you specify the exact formulation of your problem, a clean and efficient algorithm which does not generate duplicates is perhaps a topic for a separate question.